# How to render parts of a React component in multiple places in a parent component (Render component in the middle of another component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**TLDR**: I need to do the following

```
|-----------------------|                              |-----------------------|
| Form A                |                              | One input of Form B   |
|-----------------------|                              |-----------------------|
| Form B                |            ---->             | Form A                | 
|-----------------------|                              |-----------------------|
                                                       | Rest of Form B inputs |
                                                       |-----------------------|
```

**The answer:**
Make FormA a child component of FormB.

```
<FormB>
  <FormA />
</FormB>
```

And render children in FormB

```
return(
  //One FormB input
  {children}
  //Rest of FormB inputs
);
```

**Full case:**

I have a parent form component, that takes the output of 2 forms (which user has input earlier) as props.
The parent form component allows editing of both these props and combines them into a new typescript type/object.

Both of these forms are already ~300 lines of code and I would like to keep them separate, as they are different logical units.

The parent component currently has:

```
const [formAValue, setFormAValue] = useState<FormA | undefined>(formAProps);
const [formBValue, setFormBValue] = useState<FormB | undefined>(formBProps);

return(
<FormA value=formAValue onChange=setFormAValue/>
<FormB value=formBProps onChange=setFormBValue/>
);
```

The current setup is good, because

1. The validation is such that the state variables in the parent component are non-undefined only when the user inputs are valid.
2. The parent component is clear and readable
3. Components FormA and FormB are reused in different places, where user inputs data, from which we get the props for the parent component.

But the user wants the forms to be rendered like so:

```
|-----------------------|
| One input of Form B   |
|-----------------------|
| Form A                |
|-----------------------|
| Rest of Form B inputs |
|-----------------------|
```

Can I achieve this somehow while still keeping the positive aspects of the current setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make FormA a child component of FormB.

```
<FormB>
  <FormA />
</FormB>
```

And render children in FormB

```
return(
  //One FormB input
  {children}
  //Rest of FormB inputs
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's think easy, keep current structure.

My solution is, separate "one input of form B" (currently in B component) into another component. I don't think that's a hard process and make any significant changes to your project.

Comment: I think I got it. I will put "one input of form B" into new component and render it where I want. Then pass an optional boolean prop into form B telling it to not render "that one input". And lastly when I'm making my combined form in parent component, then I will overwrite the form B value with the value from my new component.

Comment: On further thinking, this approach is a bit complicated. FormA as a child component of FormB is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep complete separation between FormA/FormB in react, one way could be to place the FormB input on top using CSS.

Assuming that the input from B you need to place on top of everything has Xpx of height:

- The parent element should have `position: relative`
- FormA should have `margin-top: Xpx;`
- FormB input that must go on top should have:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
```

Comment: This would work, but in my case, I will most likely have to put this FormB input into a div as well for some positioning. Then this solution would be less readable than disabling that input for rendering and immutably overwriting that input with an input from a new component when combining the forms.